# d3.js pie chart legends slice toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm working on a d3.js pie chart application. I am trying to develop the functionality that when you click on the legend rectangles, it toggles the slice on/off as well as the fill inside the legend rectangle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3136/

legend

```
Rects
                        .enter()
                        .append("rect")
                        .attr("x", w - 65)
                        .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20;})
                        .attr("width", 10)
                        .attr("height", 10)
                        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                            return methods.color(i); 
                        })                        
                        .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
                            return methods.color(i); 
                        })
                        .on('click', function(d, i){
                            onLegendClick(d, i);
                        })
```

Comment: What is `onLegendClick()` doing? In other words, what have you tried?

Comment: I've created the function as a starting point.

Comment: What do you mean by 'toggles the slice on/off'?  Do you mean when you click on one color in the legend, the other colors on the pie go opaque, while the selected color remains bright?  Like a highlighting effect?

Comment: You need to provide us with the function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to solve your problem:

One change required in your code is to use [key functions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/#key-functions), so that d3 matches the filtered data to the corresponding DOM node. Labels seem to be a proper key in your dataset.

Simply use:

```
.data(this.piedata, function(d) { return d.data.label});
```

instead of

```
.data(this.piedata);
```

Then, in your `OnLegendClick` function, you want to select all the legend's rect and all the svg arcs matching with the clicked element.

Workflow is :

1. select the DOM elements
2. match with the selected data
3. apply changes

Here's how to do it:

```
function onLegendClick(dt){
    d3.selectAll('rect').data([dt], function(d) { return d.data.label}).style("opacity", function(d) {return Math.abs(1-d3.select(this).style("opacity"))})
    d3.selectAll('.pie').data([dt], function(d) { return d.data.label}).style("opacity", function(d) {return Math.abs(1-d3.select(this).style("opacity"))})
}
```

I let you adjust the "toggle" feature. You might also want to change the texts in addition to the arcs, for this use another selection.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3138/

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for - its more a case of closing the tween between the other slices and having the fill go transparent. http://nvd3.org/examples/pie.html

Comment: I've tried to toggle the fill's in the rects - but its not working as planned, it seems once the fill is none - it doesn't register getting clicked again - http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3139/

Comment: Regarding your second comment you should transition fill-opacity to 0, instead of setting the fill to "none". This way your rectangle will remain clickable

Comment: Regarding your first comment: You're almost there. First, remove the clicked data item from your data variable, then call the chart update function with this dataset as parameter.